How to prove the inequality $|1+x|^p\leq 1+px+2^{2-p}|x|^p$ for $1\leq p\leq 2$.
The inequality clearly holds for $p=1$ and $p=2$, yet I have no idea how to prove it for intermediate $p$. Overall, the inequality feels like an interpolation result.
My initial idea is that, given the convexity of $|1+x|^p$ for $1\leq p\leq 2$, then we have $ 1+px\leq |1+x|^p,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. (The equality holds at $x=0$). I could also show that these exists an constant $C_p\geq 1$, such that
$$
1+px \leq |1+x|^p \leq 1+px+C_p |x|^p.
$$
Then, to determine the optimal $C_p$, I have considered
$$
g(x):=\frac{|1+x|^p-1-px}{|x|^p}\leq C_p,\forall x\neq 0.
$$
If I could show that $2^{2-p}$ is an upper bound for $g(x)$, then the inequality holds. However, I have no idea how to show this, as $g(x)$ show no obvious monotonicity and its limit to the infinite does not give such upper bound.

First, let's focus on $x\ge 0$, and let
$$
f(x) := 2^{2-p} x^p + px+1-(1+x)^p.
$$
Then, we have
\begin{align}
&f(0) = 0,\\
&f'(0)= p[2^{2-p} x^{p-1} + 1 - (1+x)^{p-1}]|_{x=0} = 0,\\
&f''(x) = p(p-1)\left[\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{2-p} - \left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^{2-p}\right].
\end{align}
where in the second line we used $p\ge1$. Since $p\le 2$, for all $x > 0$, we have $1+x > \frac{x}2$, so
$$
\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{2-p} > \left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^{2-p} \implies f''(x) > 0.
$$
Therefore, for all $x>0$, we have $f'(x) >0$ which then implies $f(x)>0$.

Now let's focus on $-1\le x\le 0$. Define $y=1+x$ so that $0\le y\le 1$. Then
$$
2^{2-p}(1-y)^p + p(y-1) + 1 - y^p \ge (1-y)^p + p(y-1) + 1 - y^p =: g(y).
$$
Then, we have
\begin{align}
&g(1) =0,\\
&g'(0) = p[-(1-y)^{p-1} + 1 - y^{p-1}]|_{y=0} = 0,\\
&g'(1) = p[-(1-y)^{p-1} + 1 - y^{p-1}]|_{y=1} = 0,\\
&g''(y) = p(p-1)\left[\left(\frac{1}{1-y}\right)^{2-p} - \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)^{2-p}\right]
\end{align}
where in the second and third lines we used $p\ge1$. It is clear that $g''(y)$ has exactly one root at $y=\frac12$. Moreover, $g''(y) < 0$ for $y<\frac12$ and $g''(y) > 0$ for $y>\frac12$, so $g'(y)$ has a minimum at $y=\frac12$. Since $g'(0) = g'(1) = 0$, we conclude that $g'(y)<0$ for all $0<y<1$. Therefore, $g(y) \ge 0$ for all $0\le y\le 1$.

Finally, let's focus on $x\le -1$. Define $z = -1-x$ so that $z\ge 0$. Let
$$
h(z) := 2^{2-p} (1+z)^p - p(1+z) + 1 - z^p
$$
Then, we have
\begin{align}
&h(0) = 2^{2-p} - p + 1 \ge 0,
\\
&h'(1) = p[2^{2-p} (1+z)^{p-1} - 1 - z^{p-1}]|_{z=1} = 0,
\\
&h''(z) = p(p-1)\left[\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)^{2-p} - \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2-p}\right],
\end{align}
where in the first line we used $1\le p\le 2$. Now, note that $h''(z) = 0$ only at $z=1$. Moreover $h''(z) <0$ for $z<1$ and $h''(z)>0$ for $z>1$, so $h'(z)$ has a minimum at $z=1$. But $h'(1) = 0$, so $h'(z) \ge 0$ for all $z\ge 0$, and hence $h(z) \ge 0$ for all $z\ge 0$.

Thank you very much for your answer. I wonder whether there is a way to see if the constant $C_p=2^{2-p}$ is optimal in this case. I have spent days trying to figure out where such constant comes from.

@GeorgeLiu I just did some numerics and noticed that $C_p$ can be smaller for the inequality to be true. That’s a more involved computation and I don’t know a simple way to do it. But what I also noticed is that $h’(z)$ is nonnegative for all $z\ge0$ if and only if $C_p$ is at least $2^{2-p}$. While this is sufficient for $h(z)$ to be positive, it’s not necessary.

I see, thanks for your answer.
